# Making a number guessing game using custom buttons

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that continually guesses a number, asking the user whether the number is too high or too low, and adjusting the guesses until it guesses the correct number and the user says the program found the correct number. It then returns how many times it took to guess the number.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to connect my different custom buttons to different methods for adjusting the guess

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result; 
    String setUpper = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please set the upper bound");
    Scanner input;
    input = new Scanner(setUpper); 
    int upperBound;
    upperBound = input.nextInt();
    int [] guessArray = new int[upperBound]; 

    int left;   // Left edge of the unsearched portion
    int right;  // just past right edge of unsearched portion
    left = 0;
    right = guessArray.length;
    counter = 0; 


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alright, I'll find the number you picked, from 0 to " + guessArray.length, "Output", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    Object[] options = {"Too low", "You got it!", "Too high"};

    result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is your number " + (guessArray.length/2), "Guess",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[0]); 

    while (left != right-1) { // while left, right not adjacent
        int mid = (right+left)/2; 
        counter++;
        //guessArray[mid]; 

        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {  // it's to the left
            right = mid;

        }
        else { 
            if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                left = mid;
            }
            else {
                if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It took " + counter + " comparisons to find your number",  
                        "Output", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a JOptionPane, it is not possible to bind methods to the buttons. It gives you a return value and blocks the caller until a user interaction appeared.

See the Documentation for further information: [Java-Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

To bind methods to buttons, you can use normal JButtons or if you want to have a look at JavaFX, the JavaFX-Button class. This is made by listening for events on the components. A good solution may be to show the programms question- and answer-messages in a label or text-field and put a "yes" and "no" button beneath it - by clicking on this buttons, your actions are performed.

Answer (score 0):

The JOptionPane returns a zero, one, or two if you've defined 3 buttons.

Your code wouldn't even compile.  After I fixed your compile errors, your button code for calculating the next number was backwards.  Finally, I pulled the JOptionPane code inside the do while loop so the person saw the JOptionPane more than one time.

Here's the corrected code.  Take some time to try and understand what I've done to your code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumberGuessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int result;
        String setUpper = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please set the upper bound");
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(setUpper);
        int upperBound;
        upperBound = input.nextInt();
        int[] guessArray = new int[upperBound];

        int left; // Left edge of the unsearched portion
        int right; // just past right edge of unsearched portion
        left = 0;
        right = guessArray.length;
        int counter = 0;
        int mid = guessArray.length / 2;

        input.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Alright, I'll find the number you picked, from 0 to "
                        + (guessArray.length - 1), "Output",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        Object[] options = { "Too low", "You got it!", "Too high" };

        do { // while not correct number

            result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Is your number " + mid, "Guess",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);

            // result is zero, number is larger
            if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                left = mid;
                mid = (right + left) / 2;
                counter++;
                // result is 2, number is smaller
            } else if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                right = mid;
                mid = (right + left) / 2;
                counter++;
            }

        } while (result != 1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It took " + counter
                + " comparisons to find the number " + mid, "Output",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```